# Lucene indexwriter destination folder

Tags: java, lucene, indexing

I'm working on a small lucene project, where i have to index a bunch of text files. so far i've managed to create the index, i think. the code runs and i get a bunch of files called 0_.*** fdt/fdx/fnm and more.

what i want to know is, can i pick a destination folder, for the index to be created in?

i'm following this [Guide](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-lucene-to-index-and-search-text-files.html) and i define a index folder, and a files to index folder, but i can't find any parameters in the indexwriter constructor, that could achieve this.

here's my code for creating the index

```
public static void createIndex() throws CorruptIndexException, LockObtainFailedException, IOException {
    File[] files = FILES_TO_INDEX_DIRECTORY.listFiles();
    Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_33);
    SimpleFSDirectory d = new SimpleFSDirectory(FILES_TO_INDEX_DIRECTORY);
    IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(d, analyzer, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.LIMITED);

    for (File file : files) {
        Document document = new Document();

        String path = file.getCanonicalPath();
        byte[] bytes = path.getBytes();
        document.add(new Field(FIELD_PATH, bytes));

        Reader reader = new FileReader(file);
        document.add(new Field(FIELD_CONTENTS, reader));

        indexWriter.addDocument(document);
    }
    indexWriter.optimize();
    indexWriter.close();
}
```

and i'm using type File instead of string for the directories

```
public static File FILES_TO_INDEX_DIRECTORY = new File("C:\\Users\\k\\Dropbox\\Public\\afgansprojekt\\RouteLogger\\Lucene\\FilesToIndex");
public static final File INDEX_DIRECTORY = new File("C:\\Users\\k\\Dropbox\\Public\\afgansprojekt\\RouteLogger\\Lucene\\Index");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are setting the destination folder with `SimpleFSDirectory d = new SimpleFSDirectory(FILES_TO_INDEX_DIRECTORY);`

Just change `SimpleFSDirectory(FILES_TO_INDEX_DIRECTORY);` to `SimpleFSDirectory(INDEX_DIRECTORY);`.

Edit:

```
File[] files = FILES_TO_INDEX_DIRECTORY.listFiles(); //this is where you set the files to index

SimpleFSDirectory d = new SimpleFSDirectory(FILES_TO_INDEX_DIRECTORY); //here you are setting the index directory
```

You should change this line to `SimpleFSDirectory d = new SimpleFSDirectory(INDEX_DIRECTORY);`